# multiple indexes on table not used in query

Tags: mysql, sql

i have multiple indexes on my table. Two of the indexes relate to the latitude and longitude of the members and is used to calculate the distance between the members.

the problem is that after i calculate the distance between the members i then need to filter the result set by other conditions i.e

**i first want to select all member who live within a 5 miles radius.**

BASED ON that result i then want to **filter the result by member who meet other criteria**.

i am not sure if this is possible and would really welcome advise on the best way to proceed with this query.

i got the formulate for calculating the distance between members from [here:](http://clickherelabs.com/2015/01/distance-searching-and-mysql/)

below is my query.

```
SELECT *
           FROM (
             SELECT 
                u.qualityOfPictures,u.id,
                st.statement,
                ph.thumbsize
            ,
               3956 * ACOS(COS(RADIANS('51.5247725')) * COS(RADIANS(`latitude`)) * COS(RADIANS('-0.13342680000005203') - RADIANS(`longitude`)) + SIN(RADIANS('51.5247725')) * SIN(RADIANS(`latitude`))) AS `distance`
             FROM user u
             LEFT OUTER JOIN
                 members_statement st
                   ON 
                       u.id = st.id
                   LEFT OUTER JOIN
                       list_photos_uploaded_by_members ph
                   ON 
                       u.id = ph.id
             WHERE
               `latitude` 
                 BETWEEN '51.5247725' - ('5' / 69) 
                 AND '51.5247725' + ('5' / 69)
               AND `longitude` 
                 BETWEEN '-0.13342680000005203' - ('5' / (69 * COS(RADIANS('51.5247725')))) 
                 AND '-0.13342680000005203' + ('5' / (69* COS(RADIANS('51.5247725'))))
                AND 
                u.live = 1 
            AND 
                u.membershipType =1
            AND jobId IN (2,4,1)

           ) r
           WHERE `distance` < '5'

           ORDER BY `distance` ASC
```

this is the explain statement when i [image]
AND this is the query in [SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9538db/2)

This is the explain statment when i take out the other conditions and just leave in the query for the distance.

this is the query in [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb7d/26975)

[image]

these are the tables:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `membershipType` smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL,  
  `qualityOfPictures` smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL,   
  `city` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL, 
  `latitude` varchar(150) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `longitude` varchar(150) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `live` tinyint(1) NOT NULL, 
  `jobId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,

  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `quick_search` (`live`,`membershipType`,`jobId`,`city`(5)),
  KEY `latitude` (`latitude`),
  KEY `longitude` (`longitude`)
);
```

member statement table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `members_statement` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `statement` varchar(2000) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)

);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `list_photos_uploaded_by_members` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `thumbsize` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,

  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ;
```

Comment: Strange, the query you added on SQLfiddle uses `quick_search` index.

Comment: If you want to search geospatial data, then storing it as geospatial data with geospatial indexing will help a lot with performance.

Comment: hello symcbean. but how would i do that with this query. i mean, my longtitute and latititude are already indexed.